# add new value from text box in select and option in html

Tags: html-select

I have some dropdown values in select type in an html page. I want to add  some extra values to this from users, through a text box. When user enters the value and press the button the value should be added to the dropdown select box.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Blood Test: </td>
    <td>
      <select name="DragCompany"> 
        <option value="ACI Ltd.">ACI</option>
        <option value="Apollo Pharmaceutical Laboratories Ltd.">Appolo</option> 
        <option value="Beximco Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Beximco</option> 
        <option value="Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limit">Beacon</option> 
        <option value="Delta Pharma Limited">Delta</option> 
        <option value="Globe Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Globe</option> 
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your code including any solutions you have already tried.

Comment: <td> Blood Test: </td> 
  <select name="DragCompany">
  <option value="ACI Ltd.">ACI</option>
  <option value="Apollo Pharmaceutical Laboratories Ltd.">Appolo</option>
  <option value="Beximco Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Beximco</option>
  <option value="Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limit">Beacon</option>
  <option value="Delta Pharma Limited">Delta</option>
  <option value="Globe Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Globe</option>

</select> 
i want to add a new value from text box given by user

Comment: <td> Blood Test: </td> 
  <select name="DragCompany">
  <option value="ACI Ltd.">ACI</option>
  <option value="Apollo">Appolo</option>

</select>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var s = document.getElementById('DragCompany');
var inputContainer = document.getElementById('newinput');

function addtoselect() {
  if (inputContainer.value) {
    s.options[s.options.length] = new Option(inputContainer.value);
    inputContainer.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Blood Test: </td>
    <td>
      <select id="DragCompany" name="DragCompany"> 
        <option value="ACI Ltd.">ACI</option>
        <option value="Apollo Pharmaceutical Laboratories Ltd.">Appolo</option> 
        <option value="Beximco Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Beximco</option> 
        <option value="Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limit">Beacon</option> 
        <option value="Delta Pharma Limited">Delta</option> 
        <option value="Globe Pharmaceuticals Ltd">Globe</option> 
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="newinput">
<button onclick="addtoselect()">Add</button>
```